# Show axhline value python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I've placed a horizontal line in a vertical bar char (with the average), and I want the value to be shown. (pointing  to the line)

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax0 = fig.add_subplot(1, 3, 1) 
cluster2_restaurants.plot(kind='bar', figsize=(25, 6), ax = ax0)
ax0.axhline(cluster2['Restaurants'].mean(), color='green', linewidth=2)
```

[image: The graph]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set this up as an example of adding text. Set the average value at position 0 on the x-axis.

```
offset = 2
ax0.text(0, cluster2['Restaurants'].mean()+offset, cluster2['Restaurants'].mean())
```

Comment: Thank you. I put offset to 0.5 and it's great.